# Spring's application context prevents other applications from starting in same servlet container

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I have two web applications running in same Servlet container (*Tomcat*), A and B. These two connect to each other using Spring Remoting. On startup, B needs to call A to open a connection automatically, it's basically a really simple authentication call.

However since B is (*in my case*) loaded before A, B's application context blocks until the entire application is started up. What this means is that the B application will be stuck until timeouts etc. occur and only then A is allowed to start, however at this point B is now incapable of connecting to A and the required connection between two web applications won't be created.

So, how do I work around this? I'm currently hooking the connection command using `InitializingBean` and the application context is initialized using a listener.

Comment: From Tomcat Wiki at http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q27 

it seems that you cannot specify a startup order for Webapp

Comment: @Script Runner: I know, that's why I'm having this problem.

Comment: Can you show us how you're using Spring Remoting? You might be able to use lazily-initialization, depending how you've got things wired up.

Comment: @skaffman: This is basically just a simple Hello World where a single remote method returns boolean `true` if it is called, otherwise the calling end catches an exception and doesn't connect. That's basically it. Lazy initialization is fine as long as it happens soon-ish after the web app has started.

Comment: @skaffman: Forgot to mention, there's is simple time interval based retrying also in the application so it's okay if first couple tries fail.

Comment: Tried adding `lazy-init="true"` to relevant beans one by one, none of them worked because there's basically nothing that calls these beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to my mind:

- Run two instances of Tomcat, on different ports.
- perform the authentication in a new thread (preferably using an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)). Thus the "main" thread won't block and the deployment will continue.

Comment: Running the two applications in same servlet container is actually requirement so the first option is unfortunately out of the question. I'm trying to avoid boilerplate code for running the "connector" because otherwise it's going to be used just like a normal bean and that would require additional boilerplating to get it back to "normal" state.